# Python multiple csv files onto 1 plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot multiple csv files within a folder onto 1 single graph, but when I try to plot the graph and call the plt.plot(x="..",y=".."), I get an 'unexpected keyword' argument

I am unsure where I am going wrong, if anyone has any ideas, that would be great

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r"C:\Users\my_data"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
for file in csv_files: 
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=2,skiprows=1, usecols=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])  
    plt.xlabel("c") # x axis is "c" column
    plt.ylabel("d") # y axis is "d" column
    plt.plot(x="c", y="d") #unexpected keyword argument x
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `plot` function from `matplotlib.pyplot` does not have `x` or `y` keyword parameters. You can simply pass x and y (and optional formatting) like `plot(x, y, 'bo')`.

See the [matplotlib documentations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for more.